# Jquery / Show/Hide / ToggleClass - Click behaviour on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide, toggleclass

```
<h2 class="yearGroupTitle"><a href="" title="">2013</a> <span class="instructions">Show more work from this year</span></h2>
<div class="yeargroup limited">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div
```

In the example above, there are multiple instances of `<div class="yeargroup limited">`, with varying numbers of child divs. If `<div class="yeargroup limited">` has more than 8 child divs, then a `<span>` is dynamically added and hover and click behaviour added.

The click behaviour both toggles the class"limited" and swaps the instructional text.
The hover behaviour both toggles the class".hover" and adds a pointer cursor.

I am getting erratic results.

1. The hover behaviour works.
2. The text swapping works on **some of the divs**
3. The toggle behaviour on class"limited" is not working on any of the divs.

I think I am nearly there. Sorry in advance for the '*not so elegant*' code. Any help greatly appreciated.

The jquery :-

```
$( "div.yeargroup" ).each(function(){

if ($(this).children().length > 8  ) {

var showMessage = 'Show more work from this year';
var hideMessage = 'Show less work from this year';
$( this ).prev('h2').append(' <span class="instructions">' + showMessage +'</span>');
var message = $( '.instructions' );

message.hover(
function() {
$( this ).addClass( 'hover' );
$( this ).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );},
function() {
$( this ).removeClass( 'hover' );
});


message.on("click", function(event){
$(this).next('div').toggleClass("limited");    
var currMessage = ($(this).text() == hideMessage) ? showMessage : hideMessage;
$(this).text(currMessage);
});

};

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your selector `var message = $( '.instructions' );` is wrong, you need to select only those elements which are in the current iterating `yeargroup`.

So try

```
var message = $(this).find( '.instructions' );
```

Comment: @naturelab there was a errro in my code it should be `$(this)` instead I used `$this`

Comment: Still didn't work. That part of the code IS already working. It is the '$(this).next('div').toggleClass("limited");    ' part that is not working.

Comment: in that case `$(this).next` is not there because it is the last element in its parent `h2`. If you want the next `div.yeargroup` then you need to say `$(this).closest('h2').next('div.yeargroup')`

Comment: Thankyou - That makes sense - and it now works. Incredible how sometimes a supposedly 'really simple' thing throws up so many issues!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on("click",'.instructions', function(event,ele){
$(this).next('div').toggleClass("limited");    
 var currMessage = (ele.text() == hideMessage) ? showMessage : hideMessage;
 ele.text(currMessage);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Baadshah. FYI - The above is just a small part of a larger jquery file, that is already enclosed in '$(document).ready(function() {'....'});' - I implemented your suggestion and it has fixed the text swapping ( this is all consistent now - ie. on ALL divs ). However, the '$(this).next('div').toggleClass("limited")' is NOT working - Have I got the targeting wrong somehow ?

Comment: Thx for quick reply @Baadshah. Still not working, ( in fact this stops the text swapping from working as well ). It has occurred to me that I am using ( src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ) Would that cause a problem ?